# EZ USB Suite Cypress FX3 (Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, cypress

I installed the latest version of the EZ USB FX3 suite. I am using Windows 7 64 bit. After importing the project as described in the user maunual and building the examples on Eclipse I get the following error

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/Cypress/EZ-USB FX3 SDK/1.3/ARM GCC/bin/cs-make --no-
print-directory post-build
/usr/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/usr/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `C:/Program Files (x86)/Cypress/EZ-USB FX3
SDK/1.3/ARM GCC/bin/cs-make --no-print-directory post-build'
cs-make: *** [USBBulkSourceSink.elf] Error 1
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny enough we resolved this issue by just changing the main install directory.

Comment: I guess there must be no spaces in installing path.